# Hybrid APP Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobilesdk

I am trying to create the hybrid app follow this link :- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK

But when i clicked on remote access the page redirects in to app section.Any Idea how can i create the hybrid app in developer edition?

Answer (score 0):

The document you are referring is pretty old .

Here is the right link to latest documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/dev_hybrid_apps.htm

You have couple of options in hybrid. You will either create hybrid local or hybrid remote.

Hybrid remote is if you want to leverage salesforce visualforce pages to render.

Also remote access is now known as Connected app .You will create a new connected app in salesforce